# AWS - Python - Flask: Building fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

my building process always fails when I try to install jq. Could you please tell me  what I am doing wrong?

```
env:
  parameter-store:
    JWT_SECRET: JWT_SECRET

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - curl -sS -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
      - curl -sS -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
      - chmod +x ./kubectl ./aws-iam-authenticator
      - export PATH=$PWD/:$PATH
      - apt-get update && apt-get -y install jq
      - apt-get -y install python3-pip python3-dev
      - pip3 install --upgrade awscli
      - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      # - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - python3 -m pytest test_main.py
  pre_build:
      commands:
        - TAG="$REPOSITORY_NAME.$REPOSITORY_BRANCH.$ENVIRONMENT_NAME.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S).$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)"
        - sed -i 's@CONTAINER_IMAGE@'"$REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG"'@' simple_jwt_api.yml
        - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email)
        - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build --tag $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG .

  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG
      - CREDENTIALS=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn $EKS_KUBECTL_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name codebuild-kubectl --duration-seconds 900)
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')"
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')"
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')"
      - export AWS_EXPIRATION=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.Credentials.Expiration')
      - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name $EKS_CLUSTER_NAME
      - kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml
      - printf '[{"name":"simple_jwt_api","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$TAG > build.json
      - pwd
      - ls
artifacts:
  files: build.json
```

#### Error msg:

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:14 Waiting for agent ping

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:16 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src534423531/src

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src534423531/src/buildspec.yml

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Processing environment variables

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Decrypting parameter store environment variables

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Selecting 'python' runtime version '3.8' based on manual selections...

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Running command echo "Installing Python version 3.8 ..."

Installing Python version 3.8 ...

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Running command pyenv global  $PYTHON_38_VERSION

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src534423531/src

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Registering with agent

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Phases found in YAML: 4

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17  POST_BUILD: 11 commands

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17  INSTALL: 9 commands

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17  PRE_BUILD: 4 commands

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17  BUILD: 1 commands

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Phase context status code:  Message:

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Entering phase INSTALL

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:17 Running command curl -sS -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Running command curl -sS -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Running command chmod +x ./kubectl ./aws-iam-authenticator

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Running command export PATH=$PWD/:$PATH

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Running command apt-get update && apt-get -y install jq

/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 4: apt-get: command not found

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Command did not exit successfully apt-get update && apt-get -y install jq exit status 127

[Container] 2020/03/22 15:57:19 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED

[Container] 2

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clear from this line:

```
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 4: apt-get: command not found
```

Please use the Ubuntu 3.0/4.0 image which will provide Python 3.8 and 'apt-get' command. In Amazon Linux image, use 'yum' command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html